# Linear transformation $\ T(A)=2A+3A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm given a linear transformation $\ T:M_{2}\to M_{2}\  where\ T(A)=2A+3A^T$

I need to find a matrix of this linear transformation in standard basis.

$\ T(\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0})=\pmatrix{5&0\\0&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0})=\pmatrix{2&0\\3&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0})=\pmatrix{0&2\\3&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1})=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&5}$

I've found a matrix of T to be $\ S=\pmatrix{5&0&0&0\\0&2&3&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&5}$

But when I take some vector from $\ M_{2}$ I can't multiply it with matrix S. My mistake is probably in finding the matrix S.

Comment: What do you mean, you can't multiply it with matrix $S$? You'd have to write your "vector" $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ in terms of the basis you wrote, i.e., as $\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

What you found for

$$ T \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } T \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

are wrong. You also missed a $3$ when you constructed $S$ from its value on the basis matrices.